# Function being called while generating buttons with onClick property (React)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a calculator, So I have to add buttons for number 1 to 9. And I'm trying to do it in the most "programming" way by creating a function that would generate all of the buttons instead of creating it one by one.

```
  const getNumbers = () => {
    let buttons = []
    for (let i=1; i<10; i++){
      const btn = <button onClick={clickHandler(i)}>{i}</button>
      buttons.push(btn)
    }
    return buttons
  }
  const numbers = getNumbers()
```

However, when I display it (numbers), the clickHandler function is being called everytime the button is generated.

Comment: You should use an arrow function instead of direct function call.

Comment: @SMAKSS Alright, but  stackoverflow allows me to only mark one of the answers

Comment: Yeah, you should accept the one that is best suited for you and the future users who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work for you.

```js
...
const btn = <button onClick={() => clickHandler(i)}>{i}</button>
...
```

Otherwise, every time the button got created, the `onClick` function will fire automatically.

You can read more about when to bind a direct function or the arrow function to the element or component in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a reference to a function, not call it:

```
  const getNumbers = () => {
    let buttons = []
    for (let i=1; i<10; i++){
      const btn = <button onClick={()=>clickHandler(i)}>{i}</button>
      buttons.push(btn)
    }
    return buttons
  }
  const numbers = getNumbers()
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to call the function directly. do something like this

```
const btn = <button onClick={() => clickHandler(i)}>{i}</button>
```